# Time Math Guidance needed

Tags: c#, math, datetime, timespan

I have a DateTime object that is 10:00 AM
This time represents what time of day a report should be run.

I want to calculate the amount of time remaining from NOW until 10:00 AM

part of my confusion is NOW might be after 10:am or BEFORE 10am,

I keep playing around with TimeSpan, but my results are not quite right...  I am sure this is simple, but it is one of those things I have been working of for a few hours and I need a push in the right direction...

I want the timespan object timeTillRun to be correct...here is what I have tried:

```
{
  DateTime scheduledRun = DateTime.Today.AddHours(_timeToStart);//_timeToStart = 10
  TimeSpan timeTillRun = DateTime.Now - scheduledRun;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work... but you need to reverse the order of subtraction:

```
TimeSpan timeTillRun = scheduledRun - DateTime.Now;
```

Note that if it's currently after 10AM, `timeTillRun` will be negative.  You will presumably also need to check if the current time is on or after 10AM, then add 10 hours *and one day* to `DateTime.Today` to obtain the next run time.  Alternatively, you could test if `timeTillRun` is negative; if so, just add one day to it (`timeTillRun += new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)`).

Comment: before I saw @Odnxe I saw @cdhowie/s answer...I want to post my solution but I do not know how to add it to the question..but it is basically what both of you suggested...  I thank you very much!!  If I can post my solution, let me know please.

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        DateTime timeToStart = DateTime.Today.AddHours(10);

        TimeSpan timeTillRun;

        // Checking to see if current time is passed schedule run, if it is then we add a day (this is assuming this is run daily, if days are skipped like weekends for example then this would need some tweaking)
        if (DateTime.Now > timeToStart)
            timeTillRun = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1.0) - timeToStart;
        else
            timeTillRun = DateTime.Today - timeToStart;

        double totalHoursRemaining = timeTillRun.TotalHours; // get total hours remaining
        string prettyRemaining = String.Format("{0} day and {1} hours", timeTillRun.Days, timeTillRun.Hours); // can do some outputting here
```